# ASP.NET Core: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, localdb

I know this question has been asked many times, but I'm still unable to find a question similar to my scenario.

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project.
It all worked well and I can't really reproduce what if at all I did to screw this up.

It's supposed to debug using this connection string, which is retrieved from the *appsettings.Development.json* file:

```
"DefaultConnection":
  "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyProj.mdf"
```

When calling `context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();`, I get the following error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred (HResult 0x80131904):

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Shimmy\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MyProj\MyProj.Api\AppData\MyProj.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
>   **Source**: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   **StackTrace**:
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

I'm running the WebAPI as a Kestrel console app.

Here's what I've tried:

- Adding `Integrated Security=True` or `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to the connection string
- Added the full path to the connection string
- Deleting and recreating the *MSSQLLocalDB* instance
- Reinstalling SQL LocalDB

Replacing the `AttachDbFilename` flag with `Initial Catalog=MyProj`, raised this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
>   **HResult**: 0x80131904
>   **Message**: Cannot open database "MyProj" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'SHIMMY-PC\Shimmy'.
>   **Source**: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   **StackTrace**:
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

But *SHIMMY-PC\Shimmy* does appear to be in the instance's users:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work only if I pre-create the database file, which isn't really what I want but I'm not gonna fight over it.

BTW, I found a convenient way to drop/create database that doesn't cause so much trouble.
I open the developer CLI and navigate to the project/solution folder, then call `dotnet ef database`, first with `drop` then `update`.

Answer (score 1):

In the .net core environment, you should be able to fix it by bypassing the `auto-naming` part. Just add :

> Initial Catalog=MyNotAutoNamedDb;

somewhere in the connection string and it should work.

[**note**: do not replace `AttachDbFilename`!]